# How to update the existing data - attribute array in this case?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with data-attribute as

```
<div data-stuff='["a","b","c"]'></div>
```

I am fetching the existing data stuff array and update that with new value

```
var vendoritems = $('div').data('stuff');
var myid = 'd';
var value = (vendoritems.indexOf(vendoritems) > -1);
if (!value) {
    alert('doesnt contain');
// so update the data stuff array with d value so that it contains ['a', 'b' , 'c' , 'd']
    }
```

Could you please let me know how to update that ??

Thanks in advance ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :-

```
var vendoritems = $('div').data('stuff');
var myid = "d";
var value = (vendoritems.indexOf(myid) > -1);
if (!value) {
    var arr = vendoritems.push(myid);
    $('div').data('stuff', arr)
 }
```

Comment: Could you please let em know why is this code not working with Jquery mobile http://jsfiddle.net/673h38g9/16/

Comment: @Kiran..probably because in fiddle you are using very older version of jQuery that is why alert is coming undefined.

Comment: @Kiran..the problem is because jQuery version .. just read jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/) ....read what is written in additional notes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push()` to add an item to the array:

```
var vendoritems = $('div').data('stuff');
var myid = 'd';
if (vendoritems.indexOf(myid) > -1) { 
    $('div').data('stuff', vendoritems.push(myid))
}
```

Note that it should be `indexOf(myId)`.